# How can I recalculate XFS projects quota?

Tags: xfs, quota

I have a XFS formatted disk and several projects quota in it.

`# xfs_quota -xc 'report -phN'`

```
foo    20K  22.9G  22.9G  00 [------]
bar   396K   5.7G   5.7G  00 [------]
buz    12K  22.9G  22.9G  00 [------]
quota_test    96K   100K  1000K  00 [------]
```

When I try to `mv` some files from/into quota_test project, I realized `report` command gives me wrong used value.  It seems like xfs_quota is holding inode or something to calculate them.

Is there any way to recalculate specific projects quota?